# Is there a way to fast forward time in the browser for animation purposes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, time, css-animations

I am building a webpage that relies on @key-frames and animation:

It is basically a carousel that starts showing some game characters. It takes about 10 seconds for the first character to display and about 30 seconds for a large pc screen to be filled with data.

For the page logic, it would be great if I could fast forward like 30s so that the page would be filled with information after loading. Is there a way to make time pass in the browser using javascript?

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    /* height: 100vh; */
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #312a2a52;
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.carousel {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.carousel__item {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 12px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
    .carousel__item {
        max-width: 350px;
        animation: carousel-animate-horizontal-pc 110s linear forwards infinite;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 648px) {
    .carousel__item {
        max-width: 200px;
        animation: carousel-animate-horizontal-mobile 110s linear forwards infinite;
    }
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 0);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 1);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 2);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 3);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 4);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 5);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 6);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(8) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 7);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(9) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 8);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(10) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 9);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(11) {
    animation-delay: calc(10s * 10);
}

.carousel__item-head {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    /* margin-bottom: -42px; */
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.carousel__item-body {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #0000007d;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px 30px 20px 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

@keyframes carousel-animate-horizontal-pc {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-200%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    1%,
  9.090909% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    10.090909%,
  18.181818% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    19.181818%,
  27.272727% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    28.272727% {
        transform: translateX(200%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(200%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes carousel-animate-horizontal-mobile {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-200%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    1%,
  9.090909% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    10.090909%,
  18.181818% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    19.181818%,
  27.272727% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    28.272727% {
        transform: translateX(200%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(200%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.monkey-video-in {
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.common-monkey {
    background-color: grey;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 45%;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.rare-monkey {
    background-color: #e39210;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.epic-monkey {
    background-color: #870da8;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.legendary-monkey {
    background-color: #ab0603;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 45%;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='carousel'>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="a.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Cave monkey</h3>
                <div class="common-monkey">Common</div>
                <p>
                    Cave monkey is not particularly bright, but what he lacks in brains, he makes do with brute force and instincts. He can smell bananas from a 2 mile distance.
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="b.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Gatherer</h3>
                <div class="common-monkey">Common</div>
                <p>
                    A greedy miser monkey, he gathers more bananas than everyone else and never shares them.    
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="c.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Hunter</h3>
                <div class="common-monkey">Common</div>
                <p>
                    Hunter is the jungle's apex predator, no animal can escape his traps. The only thing we don't understand is why he hunts if he only eats bananas...  
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="d.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Firebender</h3>
                <div class="common-monkey">Common</div>
                <p>
                    He's discovered the power of fire and in prehistory no one messes with him. Some even call him a monkey god.
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="e.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Farmer</h3>
                <div class="rare-monkey">Rare</div>
                <p>
                    A life bound to religion and serfdom, the farmer monkey is a restless worker, able to produce large amounts of bananas at the manor's farms using medieval farming techniques.
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="f.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Guardian</h3>
                <div class="rare-monkey">Rare</div>
                <p>
                    Evolution made this monkey a true war machine. Guardian monkey is stronger, fiercer and more athletic than any other monkey. With him by your side there is no way anyone will dare to steal your bananas.
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="g.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>King</h3>
                <div class="rare-monkey">Rare</div>
                <p>
                    A true emperor of the jungle, no bananas can be farmed, sold or traded before he takes his cut. Most monkeys hate him but no one dares to stand up to him.
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="h.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Intern</h3>
                <div class="epic-monkey">Epic</div>
                <p>
                    Modern monkey life happens at concrete jungles. This young ape is intelligent and ambitious, with the right internships he may - one day - become a banana rich cryptoinvestor.
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="i.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Crypto investor</h3>
                <div class="epic-monkey">Epic</div>
                <p>
                    No one knows how he got so wealthy, but rumors say he bought BNANA's and held. Freaking legend...
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="j.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Meta monkey</h3>
                <div class="legendary-monkey">Legendary</div>
                <p>
                    The apex of intelligence and inventiveness, Meta Monkey is no longer bound by the physical world. He is a brilliant entrepeuneur and can find ways to become a banana millionaire, both online and in real life.
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='carousel__item'>
            <div class='carousel__item-head'>
                <video class="monkey-video-in" preload autoplay muted loop playsinline>
                    <source src="k.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video, please use a different browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class='carousel__item-body'>
                <h3>Cyborg</h3>
                <div class="legendary-monkey">Legendary</div>
                <p>
                    He is the last evolution of monkeys, his mind has been fully integrated with a quantumcomputer and his body was improved with last generation nano technology. Cyborg will rule this metaverse with a literal iron fist. 
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but wouldn't it make more sense to shorten the delays with media queries for larger screens?

Comment: I had thought of that before writing this question, but the problem is that shortening the delays would mess up the duration of each characters appearance in the screen, which I want to keep as 10 seconds. Can you think of a way of doing it that would preserve the 10 second duration?

Comment: Could you start the media delay at 0 seconds, and then change it to be 10 seconds after a 2 second delay?